# Extract 6- and 8-digit numbers from text string in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

long time reader, first time poster

I’ve looked for the answer but nothing that is within my skill to convert to a solution. I'd appreciate any help!

---

I'm trying to extract numbers out of a text data set in SAS, so in ProcSQL or DATAstep.

I want to return groups of numbers from a free-text field.

This field contains either:

- an 8-digit number
- The above AND a 6-digit number, which is sometimes split into groups of 2 by various punctuation
- neither

-at any point in the text, with or without text either side, of any length. For example:

```
REC    NOTES

001    Collateral 83948572 (code 56/56-55) open June 2013

002    Scoobydoo 12.12.12 88888888

003    54545454 over three years
```

I want to extract into the output:

```
8-digit no. if present     | 6-digit no. if present

83948572                   | 565655
88888888                   | 121212
54545454                   |
```

Can anyone suggest the direction I might look in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data have;
input REC $    NOTES $60.;
temp=prxchange('s/[a-z]+//i',-1,notes);
do i=1 to countw(temp);
   num=compress(scan(temp,i,' '),,'kd');
   if length(num)=8 then num8=num;
   else if length(num)=6 then num6=num;
end;
drop notes num i temp;
cards;
001    Collateral 83948572 (code 56/56-55) open June 2013
002    Scoobydoo 12.12.12 88888888
003    54545454 over three years
;
proc print ;
run;
```

Comment: You should provide at least a minimal explanation of your code. For example, the OP may not be familiar with the that regex function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  `SUBSTRING`, `STUFF` & `PATINDEX` functions.

```
SELECT REC, 
substring(STUFF(NOTES, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', NOTES), 1, '') , patindex('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', STUFF(NOTES, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', NOTES), 1, '') ), 6)AS "6digit",
substring(STUFF(NOTES, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', NOTES), 1, '') , patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', STUFF(NOTES, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', NOTES), 1, '') ), 8) AS "8digit"
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: What is `PATINDEX()`?  That looks like a MS SQL function, not a SAS function.

Comment: @Tom He is using ProcSQL for the extraction which, _i'm pretty sure_ it includes the `PATINDEX` function.

Comment: PROC SQL uses the same functions as the rest of SAS.  If you push your query into the database using explicit passthru then you can use the syntax of the underlying database.